# Current Draw vs Voltage

Tags: basic

How is it that by adding more components to a parallel circuit, the current at the root increases with no theoretical limit? Using the water flow analogy, you wouldn't find that the flow could increase up to infinity at the tap (with a constant pressure (voltage) as you create more outlets.

Comment: It does have a limit: however much the power supply can supply.

Comment: It would if there was an ocean on the other side of the tap, and the tap had minimal resistance to flow. In reality of course the tap, and your voltage source has a resistance so every load you add the apparent voltage falls a little.

Comment: All voltage sources have current limiting resistance.  Even the grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reality, the current doesn't increase without limit.

You are most likely dealing with an ideal voltage source.  An ideal voltage source can deliver as much current as needed to keep the voltage constant no matter how much current the load draws.

Any real voltage source cannot supply endless current.

A real voltage source (much like your water faucet) can only deliver a certain amount of current.

You can view a real voltage source as an ideal voltage source in series with a resistor.  This limits the maximum current that the voltage source can deliver.

Modeling a voltage source that way is often useful.  All real voltage sources have a limit to how much current they can deliver.  That limit acts much like a resistor.

You can prove it to yourself quite easily.

Find a small motor that runs on three volts.  Use two AA cells in series to power.  It will run just fine.

Now, connect the same motor to a CR2032 cell.  These have a nominal voltage of 3V.

The motor will not run when connected to the CR2032.  The little cell cannot provide the needed current.

If you measure the voltage from the battery while the motor is connected, you will see that it is far less than 3V.  The internal resistance of the CR2032 and the (low) resistance of the motor form a voltage divider.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned: the supply has a limit. In most calculations the source is assumed to be ideal so as not to influence the circuit. In reality a source will have a current limit or an internal impedance. To take your tap analogy: the tap has a 10 meter diameter and you are normally working with 1 cm diameter tubes. Thus you will not notice a reduction in flow. If you start connecting tubes with 1 meter diameter you must take into account what the tap can deliver.